# jqGrid cell editing need to position the error message dialog

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid with cell editing.  I have setup the colModel properties using the editrules option.  Everything works fine in that if I edit a cell and try to save an invalid value the grid displays an error dialog, but I need to know how to position the error message dialog that comes up because in the case of my layout it ends up behind a video.  I'm not quite sure how to hook into this and there don't seem to be any obvious options on how to do it.

In this case the dialog I would be trying to manipulate is the one with ID of info_dialog.

Also I'm using the clientArray option for cellsubmit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default value of `zIndex` parameter of `info_dialog` is 1000. The function `info_dialog` from grid.common.js part of jqGrid will be called from grid.celledit.js without usage a 4-th parameter which can change the option.

So the best pragmatical way which I could recomend you is to decrease `zIndex` value of your `div` with the video so that it will be less then 1000.

Comment: This sort of solves the problem, but the video still partly overlays the dialog in Firefox.  Not sure if it is because of the Silverlight plugin for Firefox or what.  I think they recently added some events to the info_dialog, but as of now they haven't been added to the release version of jqGrid.  I'd really like to be able to position that dialog.

Comment: I have the same opinion. I recommend you to place a feature request in  http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/.

Comment: Per Oleg's suggestion I added a request in their forum for this feature as when I asked about doing this in their forum they indicated there was no way currently to change the position of this dialog.  Anyone who thinks this is important might want to second my request.

http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/would-like-to-be-able-to-set-info_dialog-position-when-cell-editing/#p18116

Comment: @Harv I've seconded this...though I see its a bit old. Here's hoping.

Comment: You would think this wouldn't be that hard to implement considering how often they update the thing.

Comment: @Harv: Do you mean your old [feature request](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/would-like-to-be-able-to-set-info_dialog-position-when-cell-editing/#p18116)? Then I agree with you. Last time I prefer to post all suggestions in the "bugs" part of the forum. At least I could be sure, that Tony will read my suggestion ...

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is rather old but upon searching I didn't find any indication this might have been added since, so I figured now that I've figured it out I'd let everyone know how I solved the positioning of mine.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $.jgrid.jqModal = $.extend($.jgrid.jqModal || {}, {
        beforeOpen: centerInfoDialog
    });
});

function centerInfoDialog()
{
    var $infoDlg = $("#info_dialog");
    var $parentDiv = $infoDlg.parent();
    var dlgWidth = $infoDlg.width();
    var parentWidth = $parentDiv.width();

    $infoDlg[0].style.left = Math.round((parentWidth - dlgWidth) / 2) + "px";
}
```

From what I could find in the jqGrid source code, you can add a beforeOpen and an afterOpen. In my case I'd rather position the thing before it's displayed (duh!). Would be nice if there was a parameter to hook it up in the grid declaration, but this does the trick in the mean time.

I hope this helps someone! I spent most of my afternoon on this!