# jQgrid Inside jQuery simple modal problems with z-index in edit/delete/add popups

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I put jQGrtid inside jQuery simple model dialog.
z-index of simple dialog is 950 so i changed the z-index of jqGrid edit/add/delete pupups greater that that because otherwise they appearing below simple modal.

```
.jqmID1 { z-index: 1000 !important; }
.jqmID2 { z-index: 1000 !important; }
.jqmID3 { z-index: 1000 !important; }
```

All was looking good but than if i click/close "edit" and than click/clase "add" and than back to "edit" jQGrid popup again displaying below simple modal.

Than i find out than each time .jqmIDn increasing the n value for each new opening popup so my fix working only for 3 first popups ant than when value getting increased `.jqmID4 .jqmID5` .... in is not working

Is there anything i can do to fix that? should i change jQgrid.js somewhere?

**UPDATE:**

OK, as a solution to that I've found a way how to change z-index in simple modal instead, so i decrease it like that:

```
$("#myDiv").modal({

   ...
   zIndex: 800,
   ...
});
```

If someone have any another ideas let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [zIndex](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties) property of the Add and Edit Dialog. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370905/incorrect-z-order-the-jqgrid-add-edit-screen-shows-up-behind-if-you-the-grid-is/5371227#5371227) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046736/jqgrid-cell-editing-need-to-position-the-error-message-dialog/3053163#3053163) answers for details.